# Coverting 9/13/2011 12:00:00 AM to 9/13/2011

Tags: c#, datetime, date

I am getting this: 9/13/2011 12:00:00 AM

from my DB and I want to show like this:

9/13/2011

This is my code for this:

```
 litDate.Text = Obj1.DueDate.ToString();
```

My DueDate is of this property:

```
 public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you searched the MSDN for the string format options?

Comment: Check my (edited) answer below.  Nullables have extra properties and hoops to jump through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formatter "d", only if Obj1.Date is of type DateTime.

```
if(Obj1.DueDate.HasValue)
{
    litDate.Text = Obj1.DueDate.Value.ToString("d");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
litDate.Text = Obj1.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: ToString does not takes arguments.

Comment: @klm9971 : take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

This gives all the standard date format strings with examples.

Here is the example you want:

```
// Display using current (en-us) culture's short date format
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2008, 3, 15);
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d"));           
// Displays 3/15/2008
```

The answers that explicitly format the string should not be used in any case where you might have to internationalize the date.  This answer uses the culture context of the user's computer.

Comment: With a question this simple, just include an example.

Comment: See my edited code. I think you guys misunderstood my question.

Comment: @klm9971 I'm not sure how your updated question is any different from the original.  You want to format your date such that it doesn't have the time on it right?  The example I gave creates a string which only has the date.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

EDIT: Now that you revised your question to a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT datatype, you need to learn how Nullables work.  Check `.HasValue`, and if so, then `.Value` will be a DateTime, making all the rest of these answers relevant again.

Comment: With a question this simple, just include an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
litDate.Text = Obj1.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with insta's answer, you can also use

```
litDate.Text = Obj1.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```